# Class methods and instance methods - when/when not to use them?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, class-method, instance-methods

I was wondering when and when not to use class methods and instance methods. I need some practical examples. I am really confused. Another question: can't we do exactly the same things with instance methods that we can with class methods?

Answer (score 1):

Class methods:  The method isn't tied to any specific object.  In a way it acts like a free function in the class's namespace.  No 'self' pointer.  For instance [UIScreen mainScreen] is a class method because there's only one screen and there's no need to care about multiple 'screen instances'.

Instance method:  Tied to a specific object.

This applies to most OO languages, not just obj-C.

Comment: A class method is in fact tied to the _[class object](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html)_, and, just like an instance method, has a hidden `self` parameter, which points to that class object.

Answer (score 1):

At the implementation level, an instance method call contains a hidden pointer to a data structure (the object), a class method does not.

The practical question to ask is whether your call requires sending the call some specific data which is or could best be encapsulated as instance data inside an object, or not.

You (usually) can do the same thing with class methods as instance methods, but then you have to explicitly pass the object as a visible parameter in the call, which is uglier looking and also potentially disables some method override features of the Objective C language.

Comment: Class methods have a hidden `self` parameter, too; it is a reference to the class object.

Answer (score 1):

Use class methods for utility functions and Instance methods for object oriented stuff. 
Eg. For Mathematical calculation (eg sin x ) use class method. But for invoking a behavior specific to an object.. use instance method ..

Answer (score 1):

A class method as the name implies is bounded to the class. You can invoke them just with the name of the particular class. These can be normally exposed methods of a class.
For example 
 **NSArray**

`+ (id)arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)array;`.

You call it with the class name NSArray. What you expect is just a creation of a object of the type of that particular class. This doesn't need an object to invoke. Also these are very basic method required so its better to make it as a class method.

On the other hand instance method as the name implies is very much bound to the instance. Object is an entity that encapsulates state (ivars) and behaviors (methods) of a class. This can be very specific to the object. 
For example

`- (NSUInteger)count;`

Lets take **NSArray *a**  and **NSArray *b**. If **a** contains 5 items whereas **b** contains 4, instance methods called upon these instances will produce different results. And thats why we need instances to be initialized while invoking instance method. They work on the context(or state) of the object they are been called upon. Also they are not exposed as the class methods are.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use instance objet or instance variable you have to go with instance Methods.
Bcz Inside the class you cant access the Instance instance objet or instance variable.

Class methods are static methods.